# Add a narrow bar under sections bar in Szeged beamer theme

Tags: beamer, themes

[image]Can you help me sort this out.

- I need a darkred background color in the sections bar (at the top) on all slides.
- Just beneath the sections bar I need a narrow darkblue bar on all slides.
- Nothing should be displayed on the bottom bar of the slides (no authorname, no section, etc)
- All text should be in black.

Here is my simplified latex code:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% 26/05/2010
% edited by Bill Lampos
%
% Feel free to use (copy) the structure (latex formatting source code)
% but not the content of this document.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[compress,red]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>

\usetheme{Szeged}
% other themes: AnnArbor, Antibes, Bergen, Berkeley, Berlin, Boadilla, boxes, CambridgeUS, Copenhagen, Darmstadt, default, Dresden, Frankfurt, Goettingen,
% Hannover, Ilmenau, JuanLesPins, Luebeck, Madrid, Maloe, Marburg, Montpellier, PaloAlto, Pittsburg, Rochester, Singapore, Szeged, classic

%\usecolortheme{lily}
% color themes: albatross, beaver, beetle, crane, default, dolphin, dov, fly, lily, orchid, rose, seagull, seahorse, sidebartab, structure, whale, wolverine

%\usefonttheme{serif}
% font themes: default, professionalfonts, serif, structurebold, structureitalicserif, structuresmallcapsserif

% pdf is displayed in full screen mode automatically
%\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}

% define your own colours:
\definecolor{Red}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\definecolor{Blue}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{Green}{rgb}{0,1,0}
\definecolor{magenta}{rgb}{1,0,.6}
\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0,.5,1}
\definecolor{lightpurple}{rgb}{.6,.4,1}
\definecolor{gold}{rgb}{.6,.5,0}
\definecolor{orange}{rgb}{1,0.4,0}
\definecolor{hotpink}{rgb}{1,0,0.5}
\definecolor{newcolor2}{rgb}{.5,.3,.5}
\definecolor{newcolor}{rgb}{0,.3,1}
\definecolor{newcolor3}{rgb}{1,0,.35}
\definecolor{darkgreen1}{rgb}{0, .35, 0}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0, .6, 0}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{.75,0,0}

\xdefinecolor{olive}{cmyk}{0.64,0,0.95,0.4}
\xdefinecolor{purpleish}{cmyk}{0.75,0.75,0,0}

% \usepackage{beamerinnertheme_______}
% inner themes include circles, default, inmargin, rectangles, rounded

%\usepackage{beamerouterthemesmoothbars}
% outer themes include default, infolines, miniframes, shadow, sidebar, smoothbars, smoothtree, split, tree

\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars}

% to have the same footer on all slides
%\setbeamertemplate{footline}[text line]{xxx xxx xxx}
%\setbeamertemplate{footline}[text line]{} % or empty footer

% include packages
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[all,knot]{xy}
\xyoption{arc}
\usepackage{undertilde}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ceil}{\lceil}{\rceil}
%%size bibliography


%Define Symbols

\newcommand{\ds}{\displaystyle}
\newcommand{\npar}{\par \vspace{2.3ex plus 0.3ex minus 0.3ex}}
\newcommand{\R}{I\!\!R}
\newcommand{\Z}{I\!\!Z}
\newcommand{\C}{I\!\!C}
\newcommand{\N}{I\!\!N}
\newcommand{\bX}{\mathbf{X}}
\newcommand{\bD}{\mathbf{D}}
\newcommand{\bI}{\mathbf{I}}
\newcommand{\bK}{\mathbf{K}}
\newcommand{\bY}{\mathbf{Y}}
\newcommand{\bB}{\mathbf{B}}
\newcommand{\bU}{\mathbf{U}}
\newcommand{\bV}{\mathbf{V}}
\newcommand{\bW}{\mathbf{W}}
\newcommand{\bZ}{\mathbf{Z}}
\newcommand{\bQ}{\mathbf{Q}}
\newcommand{\bc}{\mathbf{c}}
\newcommand{\bC}{\mathbf{C}}
\newcommand{\bS}{\mathbf{S}}
\newcommand{\bff}{\mathbf{f}}
\newcommand{\bg}{\mathbf{g}}
\newcommand{\bx}{\mathbf{x}}
\newcommand{\bF}{\mathbf{F}}
\newcommand{\bL}{\mathbf{L}}
\newcommand{\bPhi}{\mathbf{\Phi}}
\newcommand{\bi}{\mathbf{1}}
\newcommand{\bbeta}{\boldsymbol{\beta}}
\newcommand{\beps}{\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}}
\newcommand{\bgamma}{\boldsymbol{\gamma}}
\newcommand{\balpha}{\boldsymbol{\alpha}}
\newcommand{\bmu}{\boldsymbol{\mu}}
\newcommand{\bpsi}{\mbox{\boldmath $\psi$}}
\newcommand{\bzeta}{\mbox{\boldmath $\zeta$}}
\newcommand{\bomega}{\mbox{\boldmath $\omega$}}
\newcommand{\btheta}{\mbox{\boldmath $\theta$}}
\newcommand{\bvarepsilon}{\mbox{\boldmath $\varepsilon$}}
\newcommand{\ns}{\hspace*{-0.4cm}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure}}
\newcommand{\boot}{\mbox{{\scriptsize boot}}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\DeclareMathOperator{\diag}{diag} \DeclareMathOperator{\AIC}{AIC}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Cov}{Cov}

%Define box environment
\newenvironment<>{theorem}[1][\undefined]{%
\begin{actionenv}#2%
\ifx#1\undefined%
   \def\insertblocktitle{Theorem}%
\else%
   \def\insertblocktitle{Theorem ({\em#1})}%
\fi%
\par%
\mode<presentation>{%
  \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=yellow!50!black}
  \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=yellow!20}
}%
\usebeamertemplate{block begin}\em}
{\par\usebeamertemplate{block end}\end{actionenv}}

%Bibliography
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{[\theenumiv]}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}[from second]

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
    \hspace*{0.1cm}
    %\text{short title}
    \hspace{1cm}
    \insertshortauthor
    \hspace{3.5cm}
    \insertsectionhead
    \hfill
    \insertframenumber
    /
    \inserttotalframenumber
    \hspace{0.1cm}
}
%%%%%


\title{Long Title}
%\subtitle{Tracking trends on the web using novel Machine Learning methods}
\author{Author}
%\institute{{\tiny advised by}\\ \vspace{.10cm}Professor Nello Cristianini}
\date
%{\scriptsize Intelligent Systems Laboratory, University of Bristol\\ \vspace{.10cm}May 25, 2010}

\begin{document}

\frame{
    \titlepage
}

%\section[Outline]{}
%\frame{\tableofcontents}

\section{One}
\subsection{One}
\frame{\frametitle{Abc}
}
\subsection{Two}
\frame{}
\section{Two}
\subsection{One}
\frame{\frametitle{Def}
}
\subsection{Two}
\frame{
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- I need a darkred background color in the sections bar (at the top) on all slides.

  ```
   \setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=red!50!black}
  ```
- Just beneath the sections bar I need a narrow darkblue bar on all slides.

  You choose a rather complicate theme, that has colour shadings between the elements of the headline. But maybe these colour transitions can be used for your coloured bar.
- Nothing should be displayed on the bottom bar of the slides (no authorname, no section, etc)

  ```
  \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
  ```
- All text should be in black.

  ```
  \setbeamercolor{title}{fg=black}
  \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black, bg=white}
  ```

---

```
\documentclass[compress,black]{beamer}

\usetheme{Szeged}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars}

% - I need a darkred background color in the sections bar (at the top) on all slides.
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=red!50!black}

% - Just beneath the sections bar I need a narrow darkblue bar on all slides.
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
    \usebeamerfont*{headline}
    \colorlet{global.bg}{bg}
    \usebeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}
    \usebeamercolor{section in head/foot}
    \usebeamercolor{frametitle}

    \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@barshade}{\the\paperwidth}{%
       color(0ex)=(blue);%
       color(1ex)=(blue);%
       color(2ex)=(section in head/foot.bg);%
       color(7ex)=(section in head/foot.bg)%
    }
    \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@aboveframetitle}{\the\paperwidth}{%
       color(0ex)=(blue);%
     color(1ex)=(blue);%
       color(2.5ex)=(section in head/foot.bg)
     }
    \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@belowframetitle}{\the\paperwidth}{%
      color(0ex)=(global.bg);%
      color(1ex)=(frametitle.bg)
    }
}
\makeatother

% - Nothing should be displayed on the bottom bar of the slides (no authorname, no section, etc)
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

% - All text should be in black.
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black, bg=white}

\title{Long Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{One}
\subsection{One}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{ABC}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! For the narrow bar, see my initial post, I have added an example (the color in this case is blue).

Comment: @Nadori please see my edit.